# How to trigger another jquery event using the return data of previously executed jquery event

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a button, for example

```
<a id="btn" class="button">Submit</a>
```

When this button is clicked, it triggers a jquery function

for example,

```
$("#btn").on("click", function() {
  $.ajax({
    url: 'index.php',
    type: 'post',
    data: {product_id: 1, qty: 2},
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(json) {
       if (json['success']) {
          console.log('Product added to cart');
       }
       if (json['error']) {
          console.log('Product not added to cart');
       }
    });
});
```

Now, I would like to know if it is possible to trigger another jquery event by some other jquery code, once the above function is executed, and I want to use the return values of the previous function without making any changes to the above-mentioned function.

For example, I would like to run the following function immediately after the above jquery event by writing another jquery code and not changing any part of the previous code.

```
function anotherAction(json_array) {
    if (json_array['success']){
        //calling another function
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You mean

```
function anotherAction() {
  if (submitBtn() == 'Submitted'){
    console.log('Button is submitted');
  }
}
```

But then you need to make str global in scope

Perhaps like this

```js
let str;
$("#btn").on("click", function() {
  str = 'Submitted';
});

$("#check").on("click", anotherAction);

function anotherAction() {
  console.log('Button has '+(str === 'Submitted' ? "" : "not ")+'been clicked');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="btn" type="button">Click</button>

<button id="check" type="button">Check</button>
```

Comment: But, this will run the function submitBtn() twice. Because I have already an event that calls the submitBtn() and the challenge is I should not edit the existing code. I need to write a new code that can capture the return value of the previous function. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

> without making any changes to the above-mentioned function.

No. Its not possible. `submitBtn` function's return value is unused/no-reference/destroyed inside `"#btn"` click event. So you'll never know what was returned.